# Metric space - points in an open ball

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

> Over $\mathbb{R}$ define the metric $d(x,y)=|x|+|y|+2|x-y|$ if $x\ne y$ and $0$ otherwise. Find the set of points which lie in the open ball $B(0,r)$ in the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$.

Idea: By definition of the open ball we are looking for points $(x,y)$ in the metric space which satisfy $|x|+|y|+2|x-y|<r$ for some $r\in\mathbb{R}$, and of course including the set of points where $x=y$ since on this metric we have $d(x,y)=0$. I don't know how to find the remaining points though.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you are after those $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $|x|+|0|+2|x-0|<r$; in other words, those $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $3|x|<r$. That's the open interval $\left(-\frac r3,\frac r3\right)$.

Comment: Thanks! Why is this the case though? This to me implies we are seeking points with a zero $y$ coordinate, but I don't know why

Comment: Not at all. By definition $B(0,r)=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid d(x,0)<r\}$, right?! And points of $\Bbb R$ only have one coordinate.